# Why doesn't preview pane in File Open Dialog work when application launched from Visual Studio, but works fine launched otherwise?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, preview, openfiledialog, access-rights

Even for something as simple as Notepad.exe, if I open Visual Studio on that and use "Debug > Start Without Debugging" to simply launch it (without debugger attached), then the preview pane in its Open File Dialog doesn't work. If I simply launch Notepad from Explorer or the Start menu, the preview pane works fine. Anyone know what is happening? And what can I do in my applications to enable the preview pane to work even when the application is launched from Visual Studio? (in particular, these are C++ MFC applications and C++ preview handler DLLs.. is there something about the environment or access rights token that's different for the different ways an application is launched that has to be accounted for to make sure preview panes work ok?)    thanks!

Comment: Windows native or 3rd-party preview handler?

Comment: Isn't particular to preview handler, but appears to be particular to application. i.e. Preview pane works for both Visio and files that use my handler in both Notepad and my application when launched from Start menu, but not when launched from Visual Studio. However, preview pane in Word launched either way works for both. So I suspect it's something the application can do to enable the preview pane to work even when launched from Visual Studio. Whatever that is that Microsoft added to Word, but not Notepad, I would like to do the same in my application. (or better, in handler if possible)

Comment: And for VS -> Notepad -> Notepad (IE, a grandchild)?

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment. When you launch Notepad from Visual Studio, i.e. open Visual Studio, click on "File" > "Open" > "Project/Solution" and open "c:\windows\notepad.exe" for a project, then click on "Debug" > "Start Without Debugging" to launch Notepad from Visual Studio, it will launch Notepad. Then in that instance of Notepad, click on "File" > "Open" and it will create a File Open Dialog. Click on the icon to show preview pane if not already visible. Select a file and that preview pane will not show the preview. However, launch Word like this and its file dialog previews OK.

Comment: In Notepad, go to the Windows directory, right-click Notepad.exe and click open, then in this grandchild, try the preview...

Comment: Using the context menu's Open in the File Open Dialog to launch an application (e.g. Notepad or whatever) asks the OS to launch the application, and so of course the preview pane is working fine again. It's only in applications (and only some of them.. Notepad, KDiff3, mine, etc.  but Not Word, Mathematika, etc.) launched from Visual Studio that have problems with the preview pane in their Open File Dialog. Something is different when an application is launched from Visual Studio, and there is apparently something an application can do to allow the preview window to work in that case.

Comment: The point of checking the grandchild is that environment variables are inherited. If VS -> Notepad -> Notepad works then the issue is something else.

Comment: Wrote a small app to dump information about process, env vars mostly the same, but token info (using cubiclesoft's tool on github) not. When parent process was devenv.exe instead of explorer.exe, then TokenElevationType was 2 (full) instead of 3 (limited), TokenElevation was 1 instead of 0, TokenVirtualizationAllowed & TokenVirtualizationEnabled were both 0 instead of 1, TokenIntegrityLevel was high instead of medium. Seems VS launches app with more privs than OS. Not my bailiwick, so not sure how this might matter. But I suspect, there's something an app has to do let OS allow preview.

Comment: Are the missing preview handlers registered in HKCU or HKLM?

Comment: *All* preview handlers are either working or not in the Open File Dialog for applications launched from VS, so it is not an issue with their registration, but something about the environment of the application using the Open File Dialog. Some applications (like Mathematika, Word, etc.) are doing something which others (like Notepad, KDiff3, etc.) are not. That something allows them use the Open File Dialog with a working preview pane regardless of how they were launched.

Comment: File drag-n-drop is affected in the same way, so perhaps this is related to User Interface Privilege Isolation (UIPI) (see http://patrickablog.azurewebsites.net/index.php/2010/01/28/q-why-doesnt-drag-and-drop-work-when-my-application-is-running-elevated-a-mandatory-integrity-control-and-uipi/)